# solidity - Invalid address error when invoking a function with array as an argument

Tags: solidity, web3js, private-blockchain

My Solidity contract has a function like so `function newOrg(bytes32 orgId, bytes32[] members, bytes32 head) public payable`. In my javascript file, I have this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
//
var ethereumHttpEndpoint = "http://52.x.x.x:8545";
var contractHome = "poc";
var contractName = "myContr";
var contractAddress = 0x3772385d8649.......e12e2ac2694653f79fc;
//
var abiFilePath = path.join(contractHome, 'bin', 'sol', contractName) + '.abi';
var bytecodeFilePath = path.join(contractHome, 'bin', 'sol', contractName) + '.bin';
//
var ethHttpProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumHttpEndpoint);
var web3 = new Web3(ethHttpProvider);
//
var abiFile = fs.readFileSync(abiFilePath).toString();
var abiDef = JSON.parse(abiFile);
var byteCode = fs.readFileSync(bytecodeFilePath).toString();
//
var accountAddr = '0xb16ee696fcc86065.......77d67fca2df1b2';
var myContrContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDef);
var contractInstance = myContrContract.at(contractAddress);
var orgId = '0x4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
var members = [
    '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0x4400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
];
var head = '0x4500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
//
web3.personal.unlockAccount(accountAddr, "pwd", 600, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unlock account error");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Account unlocked");
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = accountAddr;
        contractInstance.newOrg.sendTransaction(orgId, members, head,
            function(err,res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("newOrg sendTransaction failed.");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("newOrg added");
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

When I run this, I get this:

```
Account unlocked
/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:274
    throw new Error('invalid address');
    ^

Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:274:11)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:103:22)
    at /Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:89:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Method.formatInput (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:88:32)
    at Method.toPayload (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:114:23)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:139:30)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:173:15)
    at Object.web3.personal.unlockAccount [as callback] (/Users/nsubrahm/GitHub/poc/js/new-consortium.js:38:40)
    at /Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:25
```

In the array, I want to pass a byte array. Why is it getting interpreted as address?

### UPDATE

Digging some more, the error comes from an invalid address in the input to `sendTransaction`. This is raised by `inputTransactionFormatter` in `formatters.js` where, line number 103 checks for **to** address. I did try  `sendTransaction` with a `{from:accountAddr}` - leaving out `to` because
[`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) has `to` as optional. Same error.

Why is there a check for `options.to`?

```
/**
 * Formats the input of a transaction and converts all values to HEX
 *
 * @method inputTransactionFormatter
 * @param {Object} transaction options
 * @returns object
*/
var inputTransactionFormatter = function (options){

    options.from = options.from || config.defaultAccount;
    options.from = inputAddressFormatter(options.from);

    if (options.to) { // it might be contract creation
        options.to = inputAddressFormatter(options.to); //line 103
    }

    ['gasPrice', 'gas', 'value', 'nonce'].filter(function (key) {
        return options[key] !== undefined;
    }).forEach(function(key){
        options[key] = utils.fromDecimal(options[key]);
    });

    return options;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var contractAddr` should have its value in double quotes. That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Are you not taking this

```
var accountAddr = '0xb16ee696fcc86065.......77d67fca2df1b2';
```

and plugging into this

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(accountAddr, "pwd", 600, (err,res) => {
```

and getting this?

```
throw new Error('invalid address');
```

I imagine it's obfuscated for our benefit (not really needed), but the issue is still simply the input itself.

Instead of hard-coding the account, you might consider using

```
var account;
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) { 
  account = accounts[0]; // the first one
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought so too. But I can see console output for account gett8ng unlocked. Hence the confusion. BTW the account does get unlocked successfully from `geth` console.